# setcap for rhel5

Tags: linux, setcap

A quick question: I am not able to find much info to run `setcap` on `rhel5` . I searched few packages in my system

```
     # yum install libcap
     Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
     Updating Red Hat repositories.
     Setting up Install Process
     Package libcap-1.10-26.x86_64 already installed and latest version
     Package libcap-1.10-26.i386 already installed and latest version
     Nothing to do
```

I also searched binary `find / -name setcap` but it is saying there is no `setcap` command .

Answer (score 2):

A simple `rpm -ql libcap` would have showed that it provided only a library (no program), as seen in the result from [rpmfind](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/5.11/x86_64/CentOS/libcap-1.10-26.x86_64.html).  The `setcap` program came with [libcap**2**](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.7/x86_64/Packages/libcap-2.16-5.5.el6.x86_64.html) in rhel6.  There are a few repositories offering more/less compatible rpms:

- [libcap2 rpm build for : RedHat EL 5. For other distributions click libcap2.](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/16932491/dir/redhat_el_5/com/libcap2-2.22-1.el5.pp.x86_64.rpm.html)

but there always is the possibility to rebuild from the source-rpm, since the spec-file has minimal requirements:

```
BuildRequires: libattr-devel pam-devel
```

e.g.,

```
rpmbuild --rebuild libcap-2.16-5.5.el6.src.rpm
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need `libcap2`, check if that exists in the repos.

Comment: thanks @scarpino , lipcap2 is not in repository. i am trying some online rpm archives